# Require parameter if another argument is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, signature

Following is an example of what I would like to do.

```
def f(a, b, c):
    if a == 'method1':
        c = 0
    return b + c
```

In this function, parameter `c` is unneeded if the condition `a='method1'` is satisfied.
Still, I can call the function with `f(a='method1', b=1, c=2)`, which will have the same effect as `f(a='method1', b=1, c=0)`.

A solution to this is to set the parameter `c` default to `0`

```
def f(a, b, c=0):
    if a == 'method1':
        c = 0
    return b + c
```

Now I can call `f(a='method1',b=1)`, which is exactly what I want. The problem is, I can still change the parameter `c` in the call `f(a='method1',b=1,c=1)`, which I do not want the user to be able to.

Can I enforce this condition in the function signature, and not in the body (i.e. I would not like to use `if` in the body). Or if there is another better solution, please tell.

Something like

```
def f(a, b, c = 0 if a == 'method1', else c is required):
    return b + c
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use optional parameters and parameter validation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But using optional arguments still **allows** the user to pass argument `c` in even if `a == 'method1'`. I actually tend to think it's impossible to do what drakedog wants, since your solution is good enough for all practical usecases I can think of, but I'm really intrested to see if someone can find a solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you mean, like my second example? I cannot do better than that?

Comment: I suppose you could build an interface-specific fluent interface.  But why go through all the trouble?

Comment: In your second case, even if the user specify another value for c, it won't affect the outcome because you override `c` if `a` is set anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a`, `b` and `c` are all assigned dynamically at runtime. There is no way you can make up for this in the signature. It needs to be detected at runtime and you might as well do that in an `if` as anywhere else. You can specialize at the function name level, though, and python will take care of detecting the number of parameters.

```
def f(b,c):
    return b + c

def f_method1(b):
    return f(b, 0)

def f_method2(half_a_c):
    return f(0, half_a_c*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... this almost seems like something that you should be able to do with `functools.singledispatch` and `typing.Literal`, but I can't quite get them to work together at least in python 3.7 (with `Literal` coming from the `typing_extensions` module).  I think that in general `singledispatch` is probably the only tool that will really get what you've asked for as the different registered functions can have entirely different signatures.  However, to do this our methods need to be different classes.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class Method1():
    pass

class OtherMethods():
    pass

@singledispatch
def f(method, b, c):
    return b + c

@f.register(Method1)
def _(method, b):
    return b

f(Method1(), 12)  # returns 12
f(Method1(), 12, 7) # raises an error
f(OtherMethods(), 12) # raises an error
f(OtherMethods(), 12, 7) # returns 19
```

Now this is not exactly what you asked for but the arguments are enforced in the signature.

If someone who knows more about the implementation of `singledispatch` and `Literal` comes by maybe they can explain the interaction between the two.

One easier thing to do would be to simply define `c` to default to some invalid value.

```
def f(a, b, c=None):
    if a == 'method1':
        c = 0
    return b + c
```

This solves the problem that if the user forgets to set `c` for a method besides `method1` they'll receive a (possibly cryptic) error message.  However it doesn't fix the fact that if they set `c` when using `method1` that value will be silently ignored and possibly cause confusion.